# Relation between quantum numbers $j$ and $\ell$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, quantum-spin

I'm given the following problem:

"Consider an **atom** with orbital angular momentum $l$. What are the possible values of the total angular momentum quantum number $j$? Treat the case of $\ell = 0$ differently."

So I know that $j = \ell+s$ or $j = |\ell-s|$. But I'm not sure what $l$ or $s$ for the atom would be? What are the various cases, and why would $\ell = 0$ be treated differently?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qangm.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is quite a complicated question, but given the type of question asked and the notation used, I'll give what I assume to be the answer you seek.

The spin of the (presumably single-valence-electron) atom in this case means the spin of the electron, $s=1/2$. This means there are two possible values of the total: $j=l+1/2$ and $j=l-1/2$.

There is one exception to this among integer values of $l$: because $j$ must be positive, if $l=0$, we can only have $j=1/2$. The "treat this case differently" language is a little misleading, that's all.

Comment: I would add that if $l=0$, then there is no distinguished direction to compare with the direction of the spin vector. Generally the picture of processing angular momentum/spin vectors is very helpful to get a grasp of this.

Comment: This is clearly a homework question. Fortunately your answer is not very accurate. There btw is nothing "misleading" about the l=0 hint.

Comment: @my2cts I believe the "treat l=0 differently" hint is misleading, because $j$ ranges from $l+s$ to $|l-s|$ in integer steps for all $l$ including zero. One need not treat that case differently, unless more detail like the vector picture mentioned in Paul's comment was specifically asked about. What makes this answer not accurate?